# How does one use indexing properly when using statsmodels OLS in a pandas groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Like others before me (e.g., questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36321455/ols-regression-with-groupby)), I am attempting to use statsmodels OLS within a pandas groupby. However, in trying to send the results' residuals to a column in the extant dataframe, I run up against either indexing ValueErrors (if I use apply) or else KeyErrors (if I use transform).

My current code is:

```
def regression_residuals(df, **kwargs):
    X = df[kwargs['x_column']]
    y = df[kwargs['y_column']]
    regr_ols = sm.OLS(y,X).fit()
    resid = regr_ols.resid.reset_index(drop=True)
    return resid

df['residuals'] = df.groupby(['year_and_month']).apply(
regression_residuals, x_column = 'x_var', y_column = 'y_var')
```

As is, the code yields a result of "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1", while changing apply to transform results in "KeyError: ('x_var', 'occurred at index item_label')". From debug-output it appears that the creation of the residuals seems correct, but it's having a hard time placing the residuals series back into groupby with the correct indexing. However, it's not apparent what would correctly do that.

If I try to use the for-loop iteration through the DataFrameGroupBy's as in the question I had cited, the original frame remains unmodified. As a result, things like

```
grps = df.groupby(['year_and_month'])
for year_month, grp in grps:
    grp['residuals'] = apply_reg_resid(grp, x_column = 'x_var', y_column = 'y_var')
```

are of no use here, as it does nothing to the original df.

What should I more properly be doing?

Thanks all for any help.

EDIT:
Hi all, I'm apparently unable to post an answer my own question, but I think I've found out the solution. Using:

```
def regression_residuals(df, **kwargs):
    X = df[kwargs.pop('x_column')].values
    y = df[kwargs.pop('y_column')].values
    X = sm.add_constant(X, prepend=False)
    regr_ols = sm.OLS(y,X).fit()
    resid = regr_ols.resid
    df_resid = pd.DataFrame(resid, index=df.index)
    return resid
```

seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to answer my question. It is:

```
def regression_residuals(df, **kwargs):
    X = df[kwargs.pop('x_column')]
    y = df[kwargs.pop('y_column')]
    X = sm.add_constant(X, prepend=False)
    regr_ols = sm.OLS(y,X).fit()
    resid = regr_ols.resid
    df_resid = pd.DataFrame(resid, index=df.index)
    return resid
```